# Running long process on Php/Apache/Ubuntu

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to run long process on Php/Apache/Ubuntu (AWS)

This is a simple process that builds a cache during the night.

The process can run for a few hours, and is initiate by `crontab` accessing a special url with `curl`.

Sometimes the process stops at a random with no error, I suspect that it is killed by the `apache`, although I set

```
    @set_time_limit(0);
    @ini_set('max_execution_time', -1);
```

Is it a known issue with Php/Apache/Ubuntu?

Is there a way to solve it?

Currently, my solution is to run the process every 5 minutes, and store the state on the disk, and continue from where it stopped.

But I would like to know more about this issue and if there is a better way to tackle it?

NOTE:
The process stops randomly or doesn't stop at all - the longer the process (i.e. bigger cache) the chance it will stop is higher

Comment: Does it always stop at (approximately) the same time?

Comment: The process stops randomly or doesn't stop at all - the longer the process (i.e. bigger cache) the chance it will stop is higher

Comment: Is there enough RAM?

Comment: Yes, the process is very simple, it fetches HTML pages and store them on disk

Comment: Do you need apache in the equation? Can you just put a php interpreter on the #! line and run that directly from cron? (I bet you can.)

Comment: sure I can, but (1) are you sure it will not die as well? (2) my code is build on top of `Open Source` that loads the necessary env, I don't want to waste time implementing it for CLI

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason is that the client disconnects (e.g. after a timeout): PHP stops the request processing by default in this case. To prevent this, you can use [ignore_user_abort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php):

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
```

---

Also note that the `set_time_limit` call may actually fail (e.g. on a restricted environment) — so it might make sense to remove the error suppression (`@`) or explicitly check whether `set_time_limit(0)` returned `true`.